# 2 кнопки объединить в одну html

Tags: javascript

Есть 2 кнопки, одна при нажатии скрывает содержимое сайта, вторая запускаем процесс. Как бы это объединить в одну кнопку, то есть объединить функции?

```
<button onclick="showRoulette();"></button>
<button class="start" onclick="start()">START</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Можете поставить Триггер и  обращаться  к нему при нажатии на  кнопку (Если речь о переменном использовании функции)

```
 <button onclick="clicker()">Клик</button>
```

```
        var triger = false;
        function clicker(){
            if(!triger){
                console.log("Первое действие")
            }else{
                console.log("Второе действие")
            }
            triger=!triger
        }
```

Если  же требуется по нажатии на кнопку вызвать несколько функций почему бы не использовать функцию с вызовом.

```
function clicker(){
            a();
            b();
        }
        function a(){
            console.log("Первое действие")
        }
        function b(){
            console.log("Второе действие")
        }
```

Comment: Теперь из-за того что 2 функции активируются одновременно то пропала анимация рулетки. Нужно чтоб первая кнопка активировалась сразу, а как раскроет главную страницу, запустилась 2 кнопка ( запуск рулетки )

Answer (score 0):

Можно так, если нужно менять стили для кнопки:

```js
const button = document.querySelector('button');

const handleClick = () => {
  if (button.classList.contains('active')) {
    start();
  } else {
    showRoulette();
  }
  
  button.classList.toggle('active');
}

button.addEventListener('click', handleClick);
```

```html
<button class="start active">START</button>
```

Comment: Теперь из-за того что 2 функции активируются одновременно то пропала анимация рулетки. Нужно чтоб первая кнопка активировалась сразу, а как раскроет главную страницу, запустилась 2 кнопка ( запуск рулетки )